# How to integrate PHP application and ADFS using SAML 2.0

Tags: php, integration, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

Recently I started a conversation about an integration of my company's application to the ADFS of our client.
Their team generated a XML (FederationMetadata.xml) and gave it to us, now they're asking for a XML that should be generated by us and imported into their ADFS.
I have no idea what this XML I need to generate is.
Searching on internet I haven't found anything in this way, which made me question if that is right (giving back a config xml, what configs??)

My application runs using PHP.
Is there a succinct documentation I can start with and is that concept of returning a XML (to be imported in ADFS) generated using FederationMetadata.xml right?

Thank you

Comment: If you are providing a "service" to an organization, then that service should provide safe and reliable authentication systems that aren't dependent on punching firewall holes for LDAP/ADFS authentication. SAML is a common mechanism, certainly, but your developers may be more comfortable with utilizing OIDC - it's far more flexible and doesn't really require any infrastructure change on your side (which SAML will require in order to do it right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an existing library for SAML. [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) is a solid option, it's very mature and widely used. The documentation is good, and it's quite easy to integrate into an existing application.